# Could not load SSL library - dll not found

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy

In my Delphi (10.3 community edition) program, I try to use Indy with the OpenSSL library, but I receive an error

> Could not load SSL library

My OpenSSL library is version 1.0.2u and I put the `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` files in my program EXE directory, and in `Windows\SYSWOW64` and `Windows\System32`.

I have installed the Embarcadero Delphi Patch [RS1033_Indy_SSL_Patch](https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/rad-studio-10-3-3-indy-server-ssl-certificate-patch).

After the exception, I call `WhichFailedToLoad()` and the result is

> Failed to load libeay32.dll

This is a simple program that raises the exception:

```
url := 'https://www.google.it';
try
  Web := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  hIOHand := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  hIOHand.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2,sslvSSLv23];
  Web.IOHandler := hIOHand;
  Web.Request.UserAgent := INET_USERAGENT;       //Custom user agent string
  Web.RedirectMaximum := INET_REDIRECT_MAX;      //Maximum redirects
  Web.HandleRedirects := INET_REDIRECT_MAX <> 0; //Handle redirects
  Web.ReadTimeOut := INET_TIMEOUT_SECS * 1000;   //Read timeout msec
  try
    Sito := Web.Get(Url);
    Sito := DateToStr(Web.Response.LastModified) + Sito;
  except
    on e : exception do
      stg := WhichFailedToLoad();
  end;
finally
  Web.Free;
end;
```

Can you help me to solve the problem?

Comment: On a side note, you should not be including `sslvSSLv23` in the `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` property at all. In this particular example, `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` will simply discard it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I put the `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` files in my program EXE directory

That is fine. That is the 1st place the OS will look for them.

> and in `Windows\SYSWOW64` and in `Windows\System32`

Don't do that! Non-system files do not belong there. ESPECIALLY if you are putting *the same files* in both folders, since `Windows\SYSWOW64` is meant only for 32bit files and `Windows\System32` is meant only for 64bit files.

> Failed to load libeay32.dll

That means Windows could not load that DLL into memory at all.  Probably because it couldn't find the dependent `ssleay32.dll` file, but more likely because you mixed up the 32bit and 64bit versions of the DLLs.  If your app is compiled as a 32bit EXE, you must use the 32bit version of both DLLs.  If your app is compiled as a 64bit EXE, you must use the 64bit version of both DLLs.

Comment: Yes Remy... I removed all versions and i re-install only 32 bit of files libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll in exe directory and i resolved the problem... is simple... but i spent many hours to this problem! Thankyou Remy, you are the best!!  ... and ... i had correct the SSLVersions :)